# Geometry triangle sides

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, triangles

Let $\triangle ABC$ be a right-angled triangle. The length of its sides are $a$, $b$, and $c$, such that $ a + b + c =22 $   and  $ a^{2} + b^{2} + c^{2} = 200 $.

$1.$ Find out the length of $a$, $b$, and $c$.

$2.$ Without using question $1$, find out the area of $\triangle ABC$.

Comment: where is the right angle?

Comment: they didn't say what's the right angle , they just said that it was a rectangle triangle.

Comment: This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Answer (score 3):

Let's say $c$ is the hypotenuse (so that $C$ is the right angle). By the Pythagorean Theorem, $a^2+b^2=c^2$, which together with the second given condition (when substituted into it) gives $2c^2=200$, so you now know your $c$, which is $c=10$. Substituting this value of $c$ into both given conditions, we now have
$$a+b=12 \quad \text{and} \quad a^2+b^2=100.$$
Solve the first equation for $b$ in terms of $a$ (or the other way around), substitute into the second equation, and solve the resulting quadratic equation for $a$. That pretty much completes question 1.

I'm not sure what exactly is expected for question 2. I suspect that we still need to find and eliminate $c$. But once we have those two equations $a+b=12$ and $a^2+b^2=100$, we can find the area, which is $\frac{1}{2}ab$, without finding explicitly both $a$ and $b$. Hint: square the first equation and subtract the second equation from that.

Answer (score 1):

ok assuming $c$ is the hypotenuse, then we have $$a^2+b^2=c^2$$ thus we get
$$2c^2=200$$ and $$c=10$$.
Now we have the system
$$a+b=12$$
$$a^2+b^2=100$$
plugging $$b=12-a$$ in the second equation then we have to solve
$$a^2-12a+22=0$$
can you proceed?